# Carrierwave and Amazon S3: retrieve image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, session, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I have a problem with S3 and CarrierWave:
I have a pseudo-form that uploads data and files, I wrote "pseudo" because it's an ajax form so data is sent with jquery to rails with a POST request. Files cannot be uploaded in this way...so I have a popup windows that upload files to rails, I save in the session the reference to the uploaded files and when the ajax request uploads the rest of the form, I link the files uploaded to the rest of the data.

With storage :file it works without any problems, when i receive the file I do:

```
uploader = ImgObjUploader.new
uploader.store!(params[:image_form][:image])
session["image"] = uploader.url
```

and then when I get the rest of the data:

```
if (session[:image] != nil) then
  obj.image = File.open(session[:image])
end
```

And my model is:

```
mount_uploader :image, ImgObjUploader
```

This code work without any problems, for amazon s3 I switched to:

```
uploader = ImgObjUploader.new
uploader.retrieve_from_store!(session[:image])
puts uploader
#obj.image = uploader
obj.image = uploader.url
```

but it doesn't work...I didn't receive an error but I don't have the image saved inside obj object. Puts uploader prints the url of amazon S3.

Anyone can help me?

Thank You.